# Cannot run Angular application as docker container. No such file error

Tags: angular, docker

Dockerfile is placed in the main Angular project folder, along with package.json and so on. Here's how it looks:

```
FROM node:lts-alpine AS builder
WORKDIR /app
COPY . .
RUN npm install
RUN npm run build
FROM nginx:alpine
COPY --from=builder /app/dist/* /usr/share/nginx/html/

CMD ["/bin/sh",  "-c",  "envsubst < /usr/share/nginx/html/assets/config/env.template.js > /usr/share/nginx/html/assets/config/env.js && exec nginx -g 'daemon off;'"]
```

In order to start a container I first run:
`docker build -f Dockerfile -t mytag .`

Then I run the image with:
`docker run -p 80:80 --env-file ./frontEnv.list --network mynetwork mytag:latest`

The error in the logs:
`/bin/sh: can't open /usr/share/nginx/html/assets/env.template.js: no such file`

So it appears the file is not copied. Any clues why it's not working?

Comment: Try to run the commands without docker and make sure that the env.template.js is copied to the `/dist` folder.
EDIT: I checked how it works in my project. When you build an application assets folder does not land directly in `/dist` folder but rather `/dist/<project-name>` so:
`/usr/share/nginx/html/assets/config/env.template.js`
should be replaced be
`/usr/share/nginx/html/<project-name>/assets/config/env.template.js`

Answer (score 0):

My comment may be a bit misleading so I'll write a regular answer.

By default, in the `dist` directory, a new directory is created. It can be changed in angular.json file in `architect` section:

```
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/project-name"
```

Let's assume that your project name is `foo`. You should change the line:
`COPY --from=builder /app/dist/* /usr/share/nginx/html/`
to
`COPY --from=builder /app/dist/foo/* /usr/share/nginx/html/`

and everything should run smoothly.